# Is it safe to return a struct with pointer members that point to internal struct arrays?

Tags: c

If we have pointers in a struct that point to other members of the struct, is it guaranteed these pointers will still point to the internal member of the struct if we return the struct from a function?

Take for example this small-size-optimized buffer struct:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct buffer {
    uint8_t *begin;
    uint8_t *end;
    uint8_t sso[20];
};

struct buffer test() {
    struct buffer buffer;
    buffer.begin = buffer.sso;
    buffer.end = buffer.begin + 20;

    return buffer;
}

int main(void) {
  struct buffer buffer = test();

  return buffer.begin == buffer.sso ? 0 : 1;
}
```

When I compile this code locally and run it, it returns 0 so `buffer.begin` still points to the start of `buffer.sso`. However, is this guaranteed to always be case or am I depending on compiler-specific RVO behaviour?

Comment: My test returned 1. It would require that the two `structs` are in the same place in memory. If you add `struct buffer buffer2 = buffer;` would you expect the addresses to magically change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The memory behind `buffer` inside `test()` functions stops existing when the function returns. All the pointers to this `buffer` and to any member inside that `buffer` are invalid after the function returns.

The following would be a valid alternative:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct buffer {
    uint8_t *begin;
    uint8_t *end;
    uint8_t sso[20];
};

void buffer_init(struct buffer *buffer) {
    buffer->begin = buffer->sso;
    buffer->end = buffer->begin + 20;
}

int main(void) {
    struct buffer buffer;
    buffer_init(&buffer);

    return buffer.begin == buffer.sso ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Memory does not stop existing. The lifetimes of objects end.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because the memory where the local variable `buffer` is allocated goes out of scope, but the pointers will still point at that area. The `buffer` allocated in main() will have a different address. The contents of that struct is copied from the function, so you would have to update the pointers.

One superior version is one that does not use pointers, but array indices:

```
struct buffer {
    size_t  begin;
    size_t  end;
    uint8_t sso[20];
};

struct buffer test() {
    struct buffer buffer;
    buffer.begin = 0;
    buffer.end = 20;
    return buffer;
}
```

This one you can safely return from the function and everything would be valid still.

Comment: Identifiers have scope. Memory does not have scope and so cannot go out of scope. The lifetime of a local object ends when execution of its associated block ends (not merely when execution flows out of its scope, as when a subroutine is called). This is important because pointers to such objects are valid even when execution is in a completely different scope of a subroutine called directly or indirectly.